# How to pass RxSwift zip with calling function response of other 2 function

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I  having  issues  in  RxSwift Zip uses ,As  i  am  trying  to  achieve response  of  other  2  function  and  send reqest  to  3rd  function .i  have  debuged  in  xcode  and  break  point  not  itself came on  3rd  function using  zip .  i  have  triyed  like  this

```
func  createOrAlterTable(_ call: CAPPluginCall) -> Observable<[[String:Any]]>{
             

    return     Observable.zip(
                    readTableFromBackend(call), getUserData(call),resultSelector: { value1, value2 in
                        print("\(value1) \(value2)")
                        self.readTableFromBackendZipperFun(sqlliteDDLStr: value1, lastFV: value2! as [[String: Any]], call)

                }).subscribeOn(MainScheduler.instance)

                   .subscribe()

                   .disposed(by: disposeBag)
                   
                   
func readTableFromBackend() -> String {

return "response Table Data"
}

func getUserData() -> String {

return "response user Data"
}

func readTableFromBackendZipperFun(sqlliteDDLStr: value1, lastFV: value2! as [[String: Any]], call)) -> [[String:Any]]


return "JSon response"
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. The functions used in the zip must return Observables, not strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the question asked, here's what you are looking for:

```
func example<T, U, V>(first: () -> Observable<T>, second: () -> Observable<U>, third: @escaping (T, U) -> Observable<V>) -> Observable<V> {

    return Observable.zip(first(), second())
        .flatMap(third)
}
```